# WPF BitmapImage Memory Problem

Tags: wpf, memory, bitmapimage

I work on a WPF application that has multiple canvases and lots of buttons. The user cand load images to change the button background.

This is the code where I load the image in the BitmapImage object

```
bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmp.UriSource = new Uri(relativeUri, UriKind.Relative);
bmp.EndInit();
```

and on EndInit() application's memory grows very much.

One thing that makes thinks better (but doesn't really fix the problem) is adding

```
bmp.DecodePixelWidth = 1024;
```

1024 - my maximum canvas size. But I should do this only to the images with width greater than 1024 - so how can I get the width before EndInit() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By loading the image into a [BitmapFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.aspx) I think you'll get by with just reading the metadata.

```
private Size GetImageSize(Uri image)
{
    var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(image);
    // You could also look at the .Width and .Height of the frame which 
    // is in 1/96th's of an inch instead of pixels
    return new Size(frame.PixelWidth, frame.PixelHeight);
}
```

And then you can do the following when loading the BitmapSource:

```
var img = new Uri(ImagePath);
var size = GetImageSize(img);
var source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
if (size.Width > 1024)
    source.DecodePixelWidth = 1024;
source.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
source.UriSource = new Uri(ImagePath);
source.EndInit();
myImageControl.Source = source;
```

I tested this a few times and looked at the memory consumption in the Task Manager and the difference was massive (on a 10MP photo, I saved almost 40MB of private memory by loading it @ 1024 instead of 4272 pixels width)

Comment: Wow, it's really impressive what a difference this made for me - not just in memory usage but in performance as well. Thanks for an awesomely simple and clear answer - for a photo gallery file browser this alone solved a number of issues I was having!